# Get long running query automated on Azure SQL databases

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

For Azure SQL databases that runs on Managed Azure Sql servers, we are able to view the long running queries on portal, however is there a way to obtain the query ID or to get alerted via any automation on the long running query in a Sql Database in Azure?

There are SQL API's supported, however it does not seem to help here with long running queries.